# RTC (real-time clock) in STM32L4 series - date and time is not updating on the debugger variable

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, debugging, rtc, stm32f4-discovery

While using the RTC (real-time clock) in the STM32L4 series, but date and time is not updating on the variable in debugger mode. But when I stop the debugging, the variable gets updated instantly and with the correct value.

What is the explanation?

Comment: Code?__________

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Variables in a debugger watch window do not update until execution is halted.  What variable display are you talking about?

Comment: Debugger? Toolchain? Configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Debuggers are notorious for not updating registers, a few workarounds include:

Copy the registers to variables and try viewing the temporary variables in the debugger. (make sure you protect them somehow to make sure the compiler doesn't optimize them out, if they aren't being used and you have optimizations turned on the temporary variables will be optimized out).

Or use the debugger 'console' or equivalent comm channel with printf statements to print the registers contents.

Answer (score 0):

By default (RTC->CR.BYPSHAD=0) you do access RTC->TR / RTC->DR via the shadow registers. The rationale behind is that you can read the time data consistently. If there would be no shadowing and if you would start reading the time register at 23:59:59.9999 and read the date register afterwards your reading would be 24 hours ahead. To avoid this, the shadow registers come into play. After reading the time register the date register is frozen until it is read out too. The drawback is that you must wait for the “end of copy” (RTC->ISR.RSF bit be set). (See RM0351, section 34.3.8 Reading the calendar)

This is done in production code but the debugger does not wait until the shadow registers are refreshed. If you want to check the time during debugging you must refresh the RTC register manually.